# my bootstrap theme showing like phones and tablets compatibility in ie 7-8?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

how to fix it
i am using bootstrap 3.1.0 it is responsive on crome and mozilla when i m running on ie
then all 'span' element showing on full horizontaly of desktop and nav tab also showing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Adding Twitter Bootstrap 3 ScrollSpy via Data Attributes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/default.js"></script>
```

please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

IE 7/8 do not support CSS3 media queries.

You will need to use a javascript/jquery solution like `respond.js` (https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to achieve "similar" functionality.

Comment: @mishraoft mark as answer if this has helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you must have to use **jquery respond.js plugin**, in order to get results in i-e. because internet explorer does not accept min-width and max-width ... you will be able to get that, by using respond.js just google respond.js and you will be doing in no time. regards